# How do I force the Android httpclient to not use a proxy?

Tags: android, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, androidhttpclient

I have a proxy configured on my android app for some webviews and it is also configured as the proxy on the system properties. Anyways the httpclient seems to be picking up that configuration and using the proxy however I don't need those calls to go through the proxy, sp is there a way to tell the httpclient to not use a proxy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this on Android you have to use the default route planner.

```
client.setRoutePlanner(new DefaultHttpRoutePlanner(schemeRegistry));
```